# Groovy pipeline if-else condition

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

So I try to set `variable` base of my job `{currentBuild.currentResult}` status.

```
script {
          
          if ({currentBuild.currentResult} == "SUCCESS") {
              HEADER_COLOR = "green"
          } else {
              HEADER_COLOR = "Red"
          }
}
```

And although the job pass and the status is `SUCCESS` the else condition is executed so I put print inside the else section:

```
else {
              echo "${currentBuild.currentResult}"
              HEADER_COLOR = "red"
          }
```

And the value inside `echo "${currentBuild.currentResult}"` is `SUCCESS`.

Maybe I need to use this `if-else` in some other way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You if-else is ok, but the way you feed it with conditions is wrong.

It should be either:

```
if (currentBuild.currentResult == "SUCCESS") {
```

or (strange way)

```
if ("${currentBuild.currentResult}" == "SUCCESS") {
```

or (the hard way)

```
if ({currentBuild.currentResult}() == "SUCCESS") {
```

or (the harder way)

```
if ({currentBuild.currentResult}.call() == "SUCCESS") {
```

WHY?

Your original `if` would always evaluate to `false`, because you a comparing an inline-closure instance to `"SUCCESS"` which is never `true`.